# Topologies that results in a disconnected topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space
(i) We call $X$ connected if there does not exist a pair of disjoint nonempty open sets whose union is $X$. (ii)  We call $X$disconnected if $X$is not connected.(iii)  If $X$is disconnected, then a pair of disjoint nonempty open sets whose union is $X$is called a separation of $X$.

Then, $B= \{[a,b)\  s.t.\ a,b \in \mathbb{R}\  and \ a < b\}$ (lower-limit topology) results in a disconnected topological space (in fact it's totally disconnected). The same could be said about $B= \{(a,b]\  s.t.\ a,b \in \mathbb{R}\  and \ a < b\}$, the upper-limit topology.  And of course the discrete topology results in a disconnected topological space.

Are my understandings correct?

Comment: The first two are not in fact topologies.

Comment: We can define the upper/lower limit topology on $\mathbb{R}$ via those basis, right?

Comment: Yes, B is a base for a topology. The lower-limit topology is also known as the Sorgenfrey line.

Comment: OK - Do the upper and lower limit topologies result in a disconnected topological space like I mentioned?

Comment: @Learner: Yes, they do.